# Is there a way to collapse and expand a ReactJS Bootstrap Accordion through an external component or button?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a simple side nav menu made using react-burger-menu, as shown here

```
    return (
    <Menu right pageWrapId={ "page-wrap"} outerContainerId={"outer-container"}>
      <a id="educationLink" className="menu-item" href="#education">Education</a>
      <br/>
      <a id="workHistoryLink" className="menu-item" href="#workHistory">Work History</a>
      <br/>
      <a id="hobbiesLink" className="menu-item" href="#hobbies">Hobbies and Lifestyle</a>
      <br/>
      <a id="contactLink" className="menu-item" href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </Menu>
  )
}
```

On my main page, I'd like to be able to click on one of the nav items that already pulls the user to the div, but now expands the collapsed accordion card as well. I have the accordions functioning perfectly fine as they would normally, but I can't find any easy method to do this from outside of the Accordion tags itself. Even with a Custom Click function from the documentation, the click doesn't work unless it's located in the Accordion in which the eventKey is also located. I have tried a custom button and function outside of it with the proper event key and nothing happens.

Example of one of my accordion divs (with some identifying text cut out)

```
  <div className="educationContainer" id="education">
                <Accordion>
                  <Card>
                    <Card.Header>
                      <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="0">
                        <h1>Education</h1>
                      </Accordion.Toggle>
                    </Card.Header>
                    <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0" >
                      <Card.Body>
                        <div className="innerContainer">
                          <p>
Blah blah
            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="innerContainer">
                          <p>
Blah blah
            </p>
                        </div>
                      </Card.Body>
                    </Accordion.Collapse>
                  </Card>
                </Accordion>
              </div>
```

Thanks!